# DNS Packet IP Address Structure

Tags: python, networking, dns

I have been writing a python program that builds a packet and sends a reverse DNS lookup request to a DNS server. I have a problem the IP address is stored in hex in a way that is difficult to understand. In the hex field it has the number of each iteration with a 3 in front of it, so 8 in 8.8.8.8 is represented in hex as '38'. Is there an easy way to make 38 in hex from integer type 8?

[image: Wireshark DNS Packet Capture]

--------------------------------UPDATE---------------------------------

So I tried using struct.pack('c', hex(ord()) and it is not packing those bytes as ASCII. I have listed a picture of the small block of code and output associated with it.

[image]

And output:

[image]

Comment: "I have been writing a python program that builds a packet" Do you use the `dnspython` library? It does everything nicely for you, you shouldn't have to go back to sniffing packets...

Comment: As Barmar said you are asking for the `A` record of `8.8.8.8` and only names have `A` record, hence your query makes no sense. But names in DNS are encoded that way: each label is encoded as length + values, and then a final 0 for the end. So 01 38 means a label of 1 byte, whose value is 38 and 38 in hexadecimal for ASCII table is digit 8. Repeat that 4 times, and add the final 0 it gives the normal DNS encoding of 01 38 01 38 01 38 01 38 00.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `int 8` to `hex 38`, you'll need to go through a few conversions.
From `int` to `string`, to `decimal`, to `hex`.

For example: `int 8 -> string = '8' -> ord('8') = 56 -> hex(56) = 0x38`

Comment: I am using struct.pack() to build the packet bute for some reason it is not packing the hex(ord) into the packet structure, its just skipping over it. I updated my post to reflect the code I tried.

Answer (score 2):

That's not an address field, it's the domain name field. You're trying to look up the IP associated with the domain name `8.8.8.8`. I'm not sure why you're trying to do this -- if you have a numeric IP, you don't need to use DNS to translate it to an address.

Domain names are represented as ASCII text, and `38` is ASCII code for the character `8`.

Comment: Sorry, I should have noted this is a reverse DNS lookup... updating post now

Comment: Reverse lookups use `PTR` type, not `A`. And the name should be `8.8.8.8.IN-ADDR.ARPA`.